# Trying to show Count of Person, Spouse, Kids

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing

```
select
    count(distinct(ssn))
    , count (distinct(ssn + spousename))
    , count distinct((ssn + spousename + kidname))
```

My problem is that if the spouse name or kid name are blank there is no spouse or kid so they should not be counted.

How would you bypass a blank value from the count?

data:

```
SSN        Person Spouse Child 

111-11.... John             (no spouse no kid) 

222-22.....Jane  Jim   Jack   

333-33.....Jerry       Jack (no spouse) 
333-33.....Jerry       Jill (no spouse second kid) 

444-44..... John Judy       (no kid)
```

My answer should be 4 people, 2 spouses and 3 kids because I am doing a count of unique values that don't include blank.

I can't show the real SSN and names so It looks like fake data
Thank you!

Comment: Please show some actual sample data, and actual desired results so we can understand your problem.

Comment: Blank or NULL values ?

Comment: You'd make it much easier for yourself if you normalised your data.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are counting the combination of spouse + child? Surely they are unrelated?

Comment: @Dale K  yes thank you!!!! 1) I can change the way the data is captured (its in a temp table)  2) I can leave nulls instead of blank 3) I can use suggestions below

Answer (score 0):

you may try COALESCE

```
select
    count(distinct(ssn))
    , count (distinct(ssn + spousename))
    , count distinct((ssn + spousename + coalesce(kidname,'')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing your data in an accurate (and of course made up!), and consumable (DDL+DML) format is critical to getting the correct answer.

Knowing whether you use null or blank is makes a big difference also.

I am a big fan of counting exactly what it is you want to count, rather than relying on distinct.

```
declare @MyData table (SSN varchar(6), Person varchar(12), Spouse varchar(12), Child varchar(12));

insert into @MyData (SSN, Person, Spouse, Child)
values
('111-11', 'John', null, null), 
('222-22', 'Jane', 'Jim', 'Jack'),   
('333-33', 'Jerry', null, 'Jack'), 
('333-33', 'Jerry', null, 'Jill'), 
('444-44', 'John', 'Judy', null);

with cte as (
    select count(Spouse) Spouse, count(Child) Child
    from @MyData
    group by SSN
)
select count(*) [Num People], sum(Spouse) Spouses], sum(Child) [Num Children]
from cte;
```

Returns:

| Num People | Num Spouses | Num Children |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(ssn) AS people,
    SUM(spouses) AS spouses,
    SUM(children) AS children
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ssn,
        MAX(person) AS person,
        COUNT(spouse) AS spouses,
        COUNT(child) AS children
    FROM
        TableName
    GROUP BY
        ssn
    ) BySSN
;
```